# Adding Header to .Net 3.5 WCF Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, header, client

I have a simple web client in c# .Net framework 3.5 that calls a SOAP service HelloWorld like this:

```
HelloService myservice = new HelloService();
string result = myservice.HelloWorld();
```

I am using some middle-ware that adds basic security by asking for an Authorization Header: "Authorization=Bearer 123456abcd" which works with a REST service, but I wanted to consume the service with the .Net client above...

How can I add the header to the Service Call?
Does exists something like: `myservice.addHeader("authorization=blah");`?

Comment: Did you create the client with "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: yes, the clients works when I don't make use of middleware. The middleware adds security and wants the Header to authenticate

Comment: I always hate that sort of middleware. It assumes everything is done manually, and doesn't take into account things like a WSDL, and having the code generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`OperationContextScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(wcfClient.InnerChannel))
      {
        MessageHeader header
          = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
          "Service-Bound-CustomHeader",
          "http://Microsoft.WCF.Documentation",
          "Custom Happy Value."
          );
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);

        // Making calls.
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the greeting to send: ");
        string greeting = Console.ReadLine();

        //Console.ReadLine();
        header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
            "Service-Bound-OneWayHeader",
            "http://Microsoft.WCF.Documentation",
            "Different Happy Value."
          );
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);

        // One-way
        wcfClient.Push(greeting);
        this.wait.WaitOne();

        // Done with service. 
        wcfClient.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
```

For Authorization

```
var messageProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
messageProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, AuthorizationHeader);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this more globally, like, for most of the operations?

Comment: Since *using with OperationContextScope* required so it's able only thru abstraction, i.e. change service call on *Func<>* for example